# In Jetpack Compose, can you check to see if a screen has recomposed?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I want to able to do something after clicking a button, but only if the screen has finished recomposing.

For example:

```
if (buttonClicked && hasScreenRecomposed) {
    doAction()
}
```

I'm not sure if there is any way on Jetpack Compose where you can wait for the screen to finish recomposing, without using delay() or waiting for the next frames. Is there any way to do this?

Edit: Added buttonClick to conditional to isolate this event

Comment: What happens if the screen recomposes for other reasons, independent of this button click?

Comment: @CommonsWare Good point, I've updated my question to incorporate the button click factor. Any ideas as to how we could check to see if the screen has recomposed then?

Comment: Your edit doesn't address the concern, as the screen can recompose multiple times after the button click, when `buttonClicked` is `true`, unless you're sure that you are going to flip that value back to `false` after the one recomposition. Overall, "do something after the screen recomposes this one magic time" feels like an anti-pattern to me. So, personally, I would try to find some other solution to the overall problem that you are trying to address via this technique.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SideEffect{}`, it executes after every successful recomposition. [Source](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects#sideeffect-publish)

```
val buttonClicked by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
val isHandledAction by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
SideEffect {
    if (buttonClicked && !isHandledAction) {
        isHandledAction = true
        doAction()
    }
}
```

> To share Compose state with objects not managed by compose, use the SideEffect composable. Using a SideEffect guarantees that the effect executes after every successful recomposition. On the other hand, it is incorrect to perform an effect before a successful recomposition is guaranteed, which is the case when writing the effect directly in a composable.

> For example, your analytics library might allow you to segment your user population by attaching custom metadata ("user properties" in this example) to all subsequent analytics events. To communicate the user type of the current user to your analytics library, use SideEffect to update its value.